# Why does yahoo mail & craigslist remember my credentials on new login?

Tags: anonymity

Yahoo mail and Craigs list seem to log me in automatically (username&PW)  when I surf to them over tor. (Even after PC shutdown, restart). I am a bit shocked that some part of the system remembers me. I am new to the system, looking for how to maximize security.

Comment: Just to confirm, you mean the Tor Browser and not the Tor client, right? They are different things and the Tor client would not affect how your browser handles cookies, etc.

Comment: Please provide more details of your PC environment. For the example, any password managers, browser extensions, etc.

Comment: Wow. Dunno. I just downloaded tor and know not difference between browser and client. Much to learn. I am on a win 10 pc. thanks for pointing me to smarter surfing practice.

Comment: no new extensions. Not using dashlane or keeepass for tor session. Left my setup as generic as possible.